# No primary or candidate key in the referenced table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have created a table `Request` which has a primary key made up from three columns, and also a foreign key

```
CREATE TABLE Request 
(
    Iqama varchar(255) ,
    Cid int,
    ReqID int,

    FOREIGN KEY (Iqama, Cid) REFERENCES Users(Iqama, ID),

    PRIMARY KEY (Cid, Iqama, ReqID)
);
```

I also created the table below which is a multi-valued attribute for table `Request`, however I am getting an error

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 51
> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Request' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK__Request_Services__151B244E'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 51
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE Request_Services_chosen
(
    Iqama varchar(255) ,
    Cid int,
    ReqId_ int,
    Servicechosen varchar(255),

    FOREIGN KEY (ReqId_, Iqama, Cid) REFERENCES Request(ReqID, Iqama, Cid),
    PRIMARY KEY (ReqId_, Iqama, Cid, Servicechosen)
);
```

and here is the `Users` table:

```
CREATE TABLE Users 
(
    ID int NOT NULL,
    Iqama varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(255),
    Password varchar(255),
    Phone varchar(255),

    PRIMARY KEY (Iqama, ID)
);
```

Comment: I'm sure this is not MySQL. However - You should use the same column order as in the referenced primary key.

Comment: if 'Iqama varchar(255)' really very poor choice for primary key.I don't think you will gain much from this index later when data are in thousands.

Answer (score 3):

The primary key in `request` is defined as `(cid, iqama, reqid)` but in your `REFERENCES` clause in `request_services_chosen` you use `(reqid, iqama, cid)`. That's the wrong order.

Use the same order.

```
CREATE TABLE Request_Services_chosen(
    ...
    FOREIGN KEY (Cid,Iqama,ReqId_) REFERENCES Request(Cid,Iqama,ReqID),
    ...
);
```